# How to calculate effective yield in C# using RATE function?

Tags: c#, excel, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the effective yield using c#. I can't seem to find the formula behind the RATE function of excel. In my research also I also found a RATE function in vb.net that the same with the excel function. I was just wondering is there a RATE function in c#?

Comment: @JohnB but ... OP already have access to the function from Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll and did not mention .Net core at all... which also makes it very unclear what else is needed... My guess source code is needed - so in this case duplicate is the right choice.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am creating an app using xamarin the problem is I need the Rate function and I don't know if microsoft.visualbasic.dll is ok with xamarin

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov is the answer provided in the link same with the function with Excel?